# Android RadioGroup getCheckedRadioButtonId inconsistant

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using radio group with several radio buttons inside. 
I implemented `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangedListener(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)`, as well as `RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`.

However, the method `RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId` always returns me one same id of my radio buttons no matter which button i click on. The listener works just fine.

I saw some posts here saying the above method works, anyone knows what's happening?  Thanks!

Comment: Do your buttons actually have different ids? Post how you create your RadioGroup.

Comment: my radio buttons have different ids, and the check change listener proves this.@dmon

Answer (score 0):

I was debugging and all of a sudden I realized the reason I got this bug.

When I created the radio group, I made it *static*, I guess the same id returned from the getCheckedRadioButtonId() is the default id.  In the checkchangedlistener(RadioGroup rg, int id), rg is never the same as my static radio group. ooops